# What are "extern char condition tricks"?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compile-time

I was reading [the GCC documentation on C and C++ function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html). In the description of the `error` and `warning` attributes, the documentation casually mentions the following "trick":

> `error ("message")`
> `warning ("message")`
>
> If the `error` or `warning` attribute is used on a function declaration and a call to such a function is not eliminated through dead code elimination or other optimizations, an error or warning (respectively) that includes *message* is diagnosed. **This is useful for compile-time checking, especially together with `__builtin_constant_p` and inline functions where checking the inline function arguments is not possible through `extern char [(condition) ? 1 : -1];` tricks.**
>
> While it is possible to leave the function undefined and thus invoke a link failure (to define the function with a message in `.gnu.warning*` section), when using these attributes the problem is diagnosed earlier and with exact location of the call even in presence of inline functions or when not emitting debugging information.

There's no further explanation. Perhaps it's obvious to programmers immersed in the environment, but it's not at all obvious to me, and I could not find any explanation online. What is this technique and when might I use it?

Comment: it's a way in C to check at compile time that a condition is true. Sort of a static assert if you will. However I cannot remember the context I've seen this. I vaguely remember a linux kernel macro that uses this trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the premise is to have a compile time assert functionality. Suppose that you wrote

```
extern char a[(condition) ? 1 : -1];
```

If `condition` is `true`, nothing happens and the line compiles to nothing. The `extern` makes sure that `a` doesn't use any memory. However, if `condition` is `false`, `a` is declared as an array of negative length, and you get a compile time error.

You probably wrap it in a macro and have something similar to `static_assert`

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(condition) extern char a[(condition) ? 1 : -1]
```